# Complicated table using rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have to make a very complicated table similar to the one in the picture below.
http://irinaciocan.ro/tehnici_web_2012/imagini/tabel_ciudatel29.png

I tried this markup but it doesn't work well.
http://jsfiddle.net/miskolc/W9nJU/3/

```
    <body>
        <table border="10" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">1</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">2</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">4</td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">6</td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="4">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" colspan="1">8</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">9</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">10</td>            
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">11</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="1">13</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="3">14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">15</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">17</td>
        </tr> 
        </table>
    </body>
```

AND the CSS

```
 td {
     width:50px;
     height:50px;
     padding:0px;
 }
```

I don't understand why cell 6 remains on the same row as cell 5 even though they are inside different tr tags.
I also don't understand why cells 1,2,3 don't have the correct spaning sizes.
Can someone please tell me how to tackle this problem?

Comment: The preview JPG you showed is a "5 column" wide template.  I suggest you first start with a row of 5 equal td's.  Then start making your other rows from top bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Your table should be a 5 columns per 8 rows table (before merging many cells).

<del>All your rows should have a total of 5 columns (or `colspan="2"` followed by `colspan="3"` by example). This is the case of the first 2 ones but then it's wrong from the third to the last one.</del>

<del>No fiddle as I won't do it for you ;) Please provide a fiddle where the table is 5C x 8R if there remain(s) a problem</del>

**EDIT**: OK solved it here: http://jsfiddle.net/W9nJU/5/

- The main problem was with the 2nd and 3rd rows: while they've a double height when displayed and make the impression that they occupy 4 rows, they should - no they MUST - be made with only 1 row each.
  So the 3 cells "1, 4 and 8" on the left span vertically over resp. 1, 2 and 5 cells (but the cell 4 is twice the height of a cell that would also be spannng over 2 rows).
  Modifcations: cell "4" spans over 2 rows (not 4); "5" and "6" no vertical span and resp. span over 2 and 3 columns; cell "7" spans over 3 rows (not 4)
- the cell "8" spans over 5 rows and not 4
- I think there was, within cells labelled "9"-"17" another value off by 1 but I can't find it anymore. Maybe not.

You're not drawing on a sheet of paper with a fixed-size grid or on a checkerboard. An HTML table is a bit like topology where size doesn't matter and a ring, a mug, a donut and Saturn ring have the same characteristics: "it's just a torus" (if the ring of Saturn wasn't made of a million rings made of blocks... my analogy isn't so good)
At the time the HTML table algorithm build the cells, rows and columns from HTML code (and it can even do so with a few cells lacking!), it has no idea of the size they will have on a graphical browser or on a printer. And a screen reader couldn't care less about that. What is important is the minimal number of cells needed. CSS then use the result to style and display it.

Comment: Based on the single row heights, I would say this template is actually 10 rows high.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Why the third one needs more columns? I thought that I have (2+1) plus 2 from the cell specified on the second row. How can I set the number of rows and columns?

Comment: @Michael 2 of the rows would be double height, yes. But you only need 8 `tr` to achieve this

Comment: OP: yes, you're right. I did not take that into account... Facepalm

Comment: And the problem was in fact that: if it can be made with 8 rows, then it shouldn't be done like that: it *must* be. I commented rows 5-8 and tried from here.... Please see my edit with a working fiddle now.